# Insert entries and link to entries from org-contacts

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, hyperlinks

I am trying to write functions that insert entries, or link to entries of my contacts org-mode file using `org-contacts`.

The functions would work as follows:

- First prompt for a contact name (maybe using the `org-contacts` command).
- On pressing `l`, insert a link to the selected contact where point was in the original buffer, then quit the temporary contacts buffer.
- On pressing `c`, insert a copy of the subtree corresponding to the selected contact and exit the temporary buffer.

I think the following commands may come in handy: `org-contact`, `org-store-link`,     `org-agenda-quit`. I am working on it right now but my lisp skills are very limited. Any idea about how to proceed would be very welcome.

Linking could be made more robust by using a setup similare to these:

- [managing bibliography in org mode 1](http://www-public.telecom-sudparis.eu/~berger_o/weblog/2012/03/23/how-to-manage-and-export-bibliographic-notesrefs-in-org-mode/)
- [managing bibliography in org mode 2](http://tincman.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/research-paper-management-with-emacs-org-mode-and-reftex/)

but this is probably even more complex.

Comment: Could you tell me why you are not happy with my answer below? Maybe, I can fix that issue.

Comment: @Tobias, I have yet to read it and try it. It looks great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you want is to wrap `org-contacts` with a special `org-contacts-mode` as demonstrated in the following.
This new major mode defines the keys <kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> as you specified it in its local keymap.

You may paste the code into your `.emacs` file after `(require 'org-contacts)` or a suitable `autoload`.

You can just call `org-contacts` instead of your proposed new function. Put point at the entry you want to insert into the original buffer and press <kbd>l</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd>.

```el
(require 'org-contacts)

(define-derived-mode org-contacts-mode org-agenda-mode "org-contacts"
  "Like `org-agenda-mode' with the following alternative key-bindings:
l: insert a link to the selected contact at point in the original buffer
c: insert a copy of the subtree corresponding to the contact at point in the original buffer
Both commands burry the contacts buffer afterwards.
")

(defadvice org-contacts (around contacts-mode activate)
  "Wrap `org-contacts' with `org-contacts-mode' where special keybindings are in effect.
See `org-contacts-mode' for further details."
  (let* ((org-contacts-buffer (get-buffer-create "*org-contacts*"))
     (original-buffer (current-buffer))
     (org-agenda-buffer-name (buffer-name org-contacts-buffer)))
    (switch-to-buffer org-contacts-buffer)
    ad-do-it
    (org-contacts-mode)
    (setq-local org-contacts-original-buffer original-buffer)))

(defun org-contacts-return (content)
  "Insert CONTENT into original buffer and switch there."
  (declare (special org-contacts-original-buffer))
  (unless (and
       (boundp 'org-contacts-original-buffer)
       org-contacts-original-buffer)
    (error "Cannot determine the original buffer.
Note, you should not manually activate `org-contacts-mode'."))
  (let ((original-buffer org-contacts-original-buffer))
   (bury-buffer)
   (switch-to-buffer original-buffer)
   (insert content)))

(defun org-subtree-string (&optional marker)
  "Return subtree at location MARKER.
MARKER should be nil or a marker pointing to a live org-buffer.
If MARKER is nil it corresponds to the current point in the current buffer."
  (let ((buf (or (and (markerp marker) (marker-buffer marker)) (current-buffer)))
    (pt (or (and (markerp marker) (marker-position marker)) (point)))
    b e)
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (unless (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
    (error "This is not an org-mode buffer."))
      (save-excursion
    (goto-char pt)
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (setq b (point))
    (org-end-of-subtree t)
    (setq e (point)))
      (buffer-substring b e))))

(setq org-contacts-mode-map (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
                  (define-key map [?l]
                (lambda () (interactive)
                  (let* ((marker (org-get-at-bol 'org-hd-marker))
                     (buf (marker-buffer marker))
                     (filename (expand-file-name (buffer-file-name buf))))
                    (org-contacts-return
                     (concat "[[file:" filename "::"
                         (nth 4 (org-with-point-at marker
                              (org-heading-components)))
                         "]]")))))
                  (define-key map [?c]
                (lambda () (interactive)
                  (let* ((marker (org-get-at-bol 'org-hd-marker)))
                    (org-contacts-return
                     (org-subtree-string marker)))))
                  map))
```

Usage-Example:
Assume you have already defined some contact with name `Nobody` and you want to insert a copy of the contact in file `test.org` at the current point position.

1. With point at the place where you want to insert the copy of the contact call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-contacts`. Maybe, you have already a key-sequence for that. You get the prompt for the contact name from `org-contacts` as shown in the following figure.

   [image: org-contacts call]
2. Input the contact name ("Nobody" in our example). You get an org-contacts buffer with all matches of "Nobody". In our example there is just one match. Place point on the match of your like.

   [image: org-contacts buffer]
3. For copying the corresponding contact into the target buffer press <kbd>c</kbd> (see following figure).

   [image: Copy of the contact]
4. If you press <kbd>l</kbd> instead of <kbd>c</kbd> you get a link to the contact as shown in the following figure below the copied contact. (Note, that I have replaced some sensitive data by three dots. Actually, you get the absolute path to the contact file.)

   [image: Link to contact]

Comment: This looks fabulous. Do you think there is a way to list all the TODOs linked too Nobody?